# XCode 13 doesn't autocomplete nor highlights/differentiate the code (C++ for Unreal Engine on a Mac M1)

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4

I'm just starting to develop in UE on a Mac M1. After trying both VSCode and Xcode, I realized that there's no decent software for coding in UE using macOS. I hope I'm wrong.

VSCode doesn't let me compile my project inside UE, so I have to restart UE every time I want to test a simple update in my code. This is simply unworkable and seems like this is the way with VSCode.

While XCode lets me compile my project inside UE, but the coding experience has been terrible since I can't get XCode to autocomplete (it only suggest some basic stuff like a "for" loop) and it only highlights some words, like "**void**, **float**, **bool**, etc" or strings like (**"This is a text"**), leaving the code like in the photo.

[Almost no color highlights. Indexing takes forever. Doesn't autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXSzx.jpg)

I've read that this happens because XCode needs to index all files first, but it takes too long. Ok, but I already wrote my code after index was finished and autocomplete still didn't work...

I just want to know if is there anyone out there having a decent experience coding on a Mac for UE? And how are you doing it?

Comment: Based on the screenshot you've shown, the files are stilling being indexed. Have you waited for it to finish indexing?

Comment: I actually have, sometimes it takes forever to index, but when it does index, nothing new happens...

Comment: Same thing is happening on macOS 12.6.x with Intel processor running Xcode 13.2.1 with Unreal Engine 4.27.x: indexing has finished but the IDE can't `jump to definition` nor display color highlights for UE data types.